# HTML form with Send button to "Email" field's address and not to site admin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form

With a contact form, a customer usually fills in their information and email etc., and when they click Send, an email is sent to you.

However, I need a form where it sends the email to the email that is populated in the "Email" field.

I have to send tracking information daily to customers and would like to do it from this form instead of an email client.

```
 <div id="form">
 <div id="name">
 <p id="username"> Name:&nbsp; </p>
 <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
 </div>
 <div id="name">
 <p id="username"> Email: &nbsp; </p>
 <input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
 </div>
 <div id="name">
 <p id="username"> Message: </p>
 <input type="text" name="message" class="textarea">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="SEND" id="btn"> 
 </div>
```

I do not know how to do the final part where the SEND function fires the correct way. If anyone can help with that please.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but be aware that you can't have multilpe `<div id="name">`, `<p id="username">`, and `<input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">` in the same page/form. Each `id` must be unique, and each `<input>` `name` must be unique per form, or the last one will overwrite the previous `<input>` `name` values.

Comment: Will this form be part of some admin area that requires user authentication by trusted users? If not, this form would open you up to users sending spam through your server.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I will fix those issues. @toxalot the form is on a receipt code genrated page, so spammers shouldn't be able to reach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this with the use of Swiftmailer. The form would look like the followning:

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php">
<div id="form">
<div id="name">
<p id="username"> Name:&nbsp; </p>
<input type="text" name="name" class="textfield">
</div>
<div id="name">
<p id="username"> Email: &nbsp; </p>
<input type="text" name="email" class="textfield">
</div>
<div id="name">
<p id="username"> Message: </p>
<input type="text" name="message" class="textarea">
</div>
<input type="button" value="SEND" id="btn"> 
</div>
</form>
```

Then the 'send.php' would look like:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.google.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('mail@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('your password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$emailTo = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Your subject goes here')
  ->setFrom(array('yourmail@here.com' => 'Your name here'))
  ->setTo(array($emailTo => $name))
  ->setBody($message);


$result = $mailer->send($message);

if ( $result > 0 )
{
    //Email was sent
}
else
{
    // Email was not sent
}

?>
```

Swiftmailer you can download from here: http://swiftmailer.org/download (just unzip to the same path as send.php)
Documentation of Swiftmailer is here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, have i downloaded and modified some of swift mailer's email with mine. But i think my HTML form example is wrong. I click send but nothing happens, it's just like a dead button. Is there any way you could cook up a quick HTML form for me that is compatible with your send.php code?

Comment: Your button should be `type="submit"` not `type="button"`.

Comment: Hi! I think it would be enough just to change '<input type="button"...>' to '<input type="submit"...>'